# Committing my git .config file to github - should I keep my github token secret?

Tags: git, github

I'd like to add `~/.gitconfig` to my `dotfiles` repository on github so that I can share it between different machines that I use.  But one of the settings is for github, as follows:

```
[github]                                                                      
    user = jononomo
    token = 3517aa3a6f1cda2f07bf6e73f30248d3
    email = me@myemailaddress.com
```

Is it important for me to keep this token secret, and therefore not commit my `~/.gitconfig` file if it contains the token?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It's really important to keep this token secret. You shouldn't commit this file on a **public** repository.

**You shouldn't even paste your real token here at stackoverflow.**

Maybe someone can access some private data with this information. The [Token Authentication](https://github.com/blog/170-token-authentication) Post at GitHub Blog says:

> Simply pass `login` and `token` to any URL which requires authentication.

Comment: Thanks.  But why is this token so important?  Don't I need my secret password to do anything with github anyway?

Comment: Maybe someone can access some private data with this information.

Comment: @JonCrowell if someone has access to your token, they can access all your private repositories and more.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `[include]` section in your `gitconfig`:

```
[include]
        path = ~/.gitconfig.local
```

Then put the private info in there and add this file in your dotfile's .gitignore.